# Laptops won't boot from USB after using DBAN

Tags: boot, usb, dban

- I used DBAN to wipe two HP laptops.

  - Then I thought I'd install a new OS so I tried both Linux and Windows
    on USB using Rufus. None of the laptops recognize the USB sticks as 
    bootable, though. "BootDevice Not Found".
  - I've tried to mess with the BOOT options but to no avail.
  - Both computers still boot from the DBAN USB stick.

Thanks in advance!
//Jonas

Answer (score 0):

A modern DBAN USB stick is probably bootable in both BIOS and UEFI styles, but Rufus-created bootable USBs may or may not be, depending on which options you chose when creating the stick with Rufus.

Perhaps you chose to create the USB sticks with a boot style that is not supported by your laptop?

Comment: So I might get better results if I try other options when making the Rufus bootables?

Comment: Maybe, depending on what you chose initially. A modern system might favor UEFI style.